# Conditional proof of ternary Goldbach

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a reference request.

I know that Hardy and Littlewood gave a proof of the ternary Goldbach for sufficiently large odd integers under the assumption of GRH.

> Is there a modern account of this proof?

Their paper is using the pre-Vinogradov version of the circle method which is rather hard to follow.

Comment: Here's a version of that proof (see pages 18-22): http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/Notes.pdf  By the way, the Hardy--Littlewood argument is better than what came later --- they put in natural smooth weights, which Vinogradov removed with sharp cut-offs, and which later ``modern" authors reintroduced!  Such is progress.

Comment: Thanks for the link! PS.I think it is also important to be able to solve difficult for sufficiently small integers, especially in analytic number theory.

Comment: Sure, but my comment is with reference to your statement that Hardy-Littlewood are using a "pre-Vinogradov version ... which is rather hard to follow."  Vinogradov's innovation was for the minor arcs, the rest of Hardy-Littlewood is pretty "modern."   For example, they note that only no zeros to the right of $3/4$ is needed, and this is not immediate!